# Maintain image ratio in IE

Tags: jquery, css, image, internet-explorer

I'm trying to maintain the image ratio in IE and I have no luck... I took a galleriffic plugin and modified it to my need's, and this is the only problem left at the moment.

Can anyone advice a simple solution? jQuery or CSS...

[Here is where it has to work (second image in IE)](http://www.turdidesigns.com/bin/ebay/donbateria/anuncio.html)

Comment: What version(s) of IE?

Comment: IE10 and IE9, older one's doesn't matter

Comment: The solution I provided should work for all IE versions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, (across *all* browsers), setting a value for one of an image's dimensions will cause the other dimension appropriately scale:

```
<img src="oo-la-la.png" width="50px" />
<img src="oo-la-la.png" style="height:50px;" />
```

You can use percentages too:

```
<img src="oo-la-la.png" style="width:100%;"/>
```

These work since browsers set image dimensions to `auto` by default. Sometimes (as in this case) you'll need to enforce this behavior yourself:

```
.slideshow_image {
    /* Set whatever width or height you like */
    width: 100%;

    /* Enforce auto scaling for the other dimension */
    height: auto !important; 
}
```